# Send message into runtime defined Kafka Topic

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a code that uses `KafkaTemplate` to send message into different Kafka topics. Topic name is received from API and can't be known in advance, the code looks like:

```java
var message = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, targetTopic)
                    .build();
kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

Now I want to refactor existing approach to use Spring Cloud Stream but it requires to define in `application.properties` topic name which I can't know.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=user-events
```

The code I use to send message with binders approach looks like:

```java
// enable bindning in config class
@EnableBinding(KafkaBinding.class)
// interfaces with output() method
@Output("output")
MessageChannel output();
// sending message to topic from application.properties
kafkaBinding.output().send(message)
```

How can I set topic name in runtime using approach with binders?

Answer (score 1):

`@EnableBinding` is deprecated in favor of the newer, preferred functional style.

You can use the `StreamBridge` to send to dynamic destinations.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_streambridge_and_dynamic_destinations